# Limits of Integration for Join Distribution PMFs

Tags: probability

I have a joint distribution function:

$$
f(x,y) = cx^2y
$$

for $x^2 \leq y \leq 1$

I want to find $P(X \geq Y)$

The solution has a double integral where the outer integral's limits are $0$ to $1$ (for $dx$) and the inner integral's limits are $x^2$ to $x$ (for $dy$).

Alternatively, the outer limits can be $0$ to $1$ (for $dy$) and the inner limits can be $y$ to $\sqrt{y}$ (for $dx$).

How do you find the inner limits of integration? I can't seem to figure out how to systematically do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Draw the region** where the joint density function "lives." We are told that $y\ge x^2$, with $y\le 1$. Draw the part of the parabola $y=x^2$ between $x=-1$ and $x=1$. The density function lives above the parabola and below the line $y=1$. Call this region $D$.

First we find the constant $c$. We want
$$\iint_D cx^2\,dy\,dx=1.$$
Express this as an iterated integral. Note that $y$ travels from $x^2$ to $1$, and then $x$ travels from $-1$ to $1$. So we get
$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\int_{y=x^2}^1 cx^2 y\,dy\right)\,dx=1.$$

Now that we have $c$, we can find the probability that $X\ge Y$. Draw the line $y=x$. Let $E$ be the region inside $D$ and below the line $y=x$. Draw that line. It meets $y=x^2$ at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Our probability is
$$\iint_E cx^2y \,dy\,dx.$$
To evaluate the double integral, express as an iterated integral. At the bottom, we have $y=x^2$, and at the top of the rgion we have $y=x$. So our probability is 
$$\int_{0}^1 \left(\int_{y=x^2}^x cx^2 y\,dy\right)\,dx.$$